# Electron set image as wallpaper (OS X and Windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, electron

How do I go about setting an image as the wallpaper on OS X and Windows? I've looked through the documentation but can't find information on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not in the Electron documentation because its not an Electron issue in the first place.

Use the library '[wallpaper](https://github.com/sindresorhus/wallpaper)' which can be found on [NPMjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wallpaper) and installed via

```
npm install --save wallpaper
```

Comment: I tried, but failed to set wallpaper on windows10.And some people come up with same problems in the `Github issues`, but no reply from the author.

Comment: I just checked the .c executable in Windows 10 without any errors, you'll have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/wallpaper) module for electron.

```
$ npm install wallpaper
```

> Note that this module works only for macOS 10.12+, Linux, and Windows 10+.
>   as on 8th April, 2019

*I am finding some solution to work on Windows 7 too.*